# Find $\lim_{N→∞}\sum^{N}_{n=-N}\left(\frac{1}{(N+in)}+\frac{1}{(N-in)}\right)$

Tags: limits

Prove that $$\lim_{N→∞}\sum^{N}_{n=-N}\left(\frac{1}{(N+in)}+\frac{1}{(N-in)}\right)$$

$$\lim_{N→∞} \sum^{N}_{n=-N}\frac{2N}{(N^{2}+n^{2})}=\lim_{N→∞} 2N \sum^{N}_{n=-N}\frac{1}{(N^{2}+n^{2})}$$
summing the terms and letting $N→∞$, and the final answer is $0$.

Where is the flaw?

Comment: A flaw I see is you have a sign wrong in one of your denominators in your first sum

Comment: Corrected already

Comment: I get $\pi$ as answer when I sum and let $N\to+\infty$. Observe that $1/(N^2+n^2)$ is both positive and even (in $n$), and thus you have done something wrong, when working the thing out.

Comment: Notice
$$2 + \frac1N = 2N \sum_{n=-N}^N \frac{1}{2N^2} \le 2N \sum_{n=-N}^N \frac{1}{N^2 + n^2 } \le 
2N \sum_{n=-N}^N \frac{1}{N^2} = 4 + \frac2N$$
It $\displaystyle\;\lim_{N \to \infty}\left[ 2N \sum_{n=-N}^N \frac{1}{N^2 + n^2 }\right]\;$ exist, it cannot be zero but a number in $[2,4]$.

Comment: Thanks I must be feeling sleepy at this time to be making such mistakes

Comment: This is a simple Riemann sum.

Comment: @Lucian: Can you please suggest me how to express this as Riemann sum? I have tried the following:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1120090/convert-to-riemann-sum

Answer (score 1):

By exploiting parity,
$$\sum_{n=-N}^{N}\frac{2N}{N^2+n^2}=\frac{2}{N}+2\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{2N}{N^2+n^2}$$
where:
$$2\lim_{N\to +\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{2N}{N^2+n^2} = 4\lim_{N\to +\infty}\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=1}^{N}\frac{1}{1+\left(\frac{n}{N}\right)^2}=4\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dt}{1+t^2}=\color{red}{\pi}.$$