# Convert to Riemann Sum $\lim_{N→∞}\sum^{N}_{n=-N}\left(\frac{1}{(N+in)}+\frac{1}{(N-in)}\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, definite-integrals, riemann-sum

The following limit has to be converted to Riemann Sum.

$$\lim_{N→∞}\sum^{N}_{n=-N}\left(\frac{1}{(N+in)}+\frac{1}{(N-in)}\right)$$

My attempt:

$$\lim_{N→∞}\sum^{N}_{n=-N}\left(\frac{2N}{N^{2}+n^{2}}\right)$$=$\lim_{N→∞}\sum^{N}_{n=-N}\left(\frac{2}{1+n^{2}/N^{2}}\right).1/N$.

Now, replacing $1/N$ by $dx$, $n^{2}/N^{2}$ by $x^{2}$ and summation by integral, we have

$$\lim_{N→∞}1/N\sum^{N}_{n=-N}\left(\frac{2}{1+n^{2}/N^{2}}\right)= \lim_{N→∞}[1-(-1)]/N\sum^{N}_{n=-N}\left(\frac{1}{1+n^{2}/N^{2}}\right)$$

$$=2\lim_{N→∞}[1-(-1)]/N\sum^{N}_{n=0}\left(\frac{1}{1+n^{2}/N^{2}}\right)=?$$

I feel that I am very close to the final answer which is $2\int_{-1}^{1} dt/(1+t^{2})$. But I am stuck after this step. please complete the rest, feel free to edit the question directly to complete the remaining steps.

With what I have done I am able to compare $a=-1$ and $b=1$, but I still need to get the general form $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{b-a}{n}\cdot f\left(a+i\frac{b-a}{n} \right)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest that you do not do the last steps, and thus not turn this into what you call the standard form. Look more carefully at
$$
\lim_{N\to+\infty}\sum_{n=-N}^N\frac{2}{1+(n/N)^2}\frac{1}{N}.
$$
Here, $n/N$ that should be replaced by $t$ varies from $-1$ to $1$. $1/N$ can be replaced by $dt$, so it is indeed the Riemann sum of
$$
\int_{-1}^1\frac{2}{1+t^2}\,dt.
$$

**Update**
Since you seem to know that you want to replace $n/N$ by your variable and you ask for the limits of integration here comes a clarification of why the limits are $-1$ and $1$ (also read the comments by @mgn):

Since the sum runs from $n=-N$ to $n=N$ the ratio $n/N$ will run from $-1$ to $1$.

**Yet another update**

Let us put the sum into the so-called standard form (although, I strongly suggest one should not do this all the time):

With $k=n+N$ and then $\tilde N=2N$, we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{n=-N}^N\frac{2}{1+(n/N)^2}\frac{1}{N}&= \sum_{k=0}^{2N}\frac{2}{1+\bigl(\frac{k-N}{N}\bigr)^2}\frac{1}{N}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\tilde N} \frac{2}{1+\bigl(-1+k\frac{1-(-1)}{\tilde N}\bigr)^2}\frac{1-(-1)}{\tilde N}\\
&=\frac{2}{\tilde N}+\sum_{k=1}^{\tilde N} \frac{2}{1+\bigl(-1+k\frac{1-(-1)}{\tilde N}\bigr)^2}\frac{1-(-1)}{\tilde N}
\end{aligned}
$$
The term $2/\tilde N$ tends to zero as $\tilde N$ (and $N$) tends to infinity, and the second term is exacly in the form called standard.

Comment: But how can you say about the limits of integration if you do not put it in standard form? Also, how will you  call it a Riemann Sum if you cannot reduce it to the general form?

Comment: mickep:Please justify your answer.

Comment: We can write $[-1,1]$ as $[-1, -\frac{N-1}{N}] \cup \cdots \cup [0, \frac{1}{N}] \cup [\frac{1}{N}, \frac{2}{N}] \cup \cdots \cup[\frac{N-1}{N}, 1]$. Then the right Riemann sum can be written as $$ \sum_{n=-N}^N \frac{1}{1+\left(\frac{n}{N} \right)^2}\left(\frac{n}{N} - \frac{n-1}{N} \right) = \sum_{n=-N}^N \frac{1}{1+\left(\frac{n}{N} \right)^2} \cdot \frac{1}{N}.$$ Please see also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum.